# jquery ajax call response in javascript is blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The fail function gives me a correct output, whereas the done function gives me blank. I am stuck with this for hours. Any idea on how to debug this?

```
var xhr = false;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

if (contentType == null) {
    contentType = "application/json";
}

var reqst = $.ajax({
        beforeSend : function(req) {
          req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        },
        url : url,
        type : "post",
        contentType : contentType,
        data : paramsTable,
        });

reqst.done(function(xhr){
alert(xhr.responseText);
});

reqst.fail(function(xhr){
alert(xhr.responseText);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to recommend you to use Ajax jQuery API instead of the old Ajax requests. No body uses it today (almost nobody; since you use it)

```
$.ajax({
   beforeSend: function(req) {
     req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
   },
   url: url,
   type: "post",
   contentType: contentType,
   data: paramsTable,
   success: function () {
     // here the code to execute if success
   },
   error: function () {
     // here the code to execute if error..
   }
});
```

#### Why your code isn't working

Because you are never using the `xhr` to send the Ajax request so it has nothing to show as the response text. Funny isn't it? hehehe.

use this:

```
success: function(resp) {
  alert(resp); // where resp is the name of the responseText here..
}
```

I have shown you how to use it. Good luck!

For more: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use standard jquery ajax structure:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    context: document.body
}).done(function() {
    $( this ).addClass( "done" );
})
.fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
});
```